# Alternative to getVertexByKey in OrientDB 2.1

Tags: orientdb

In OrientDB 2.1 the method getVertexByKey of the OrientGraph object is deprecated. What are the recommended alternatives? What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at @see in JavaDoc: the recommended one is `Iterable<Vertex> getVertices(final String iKey, Object iValue)`